# Read argument with spaces in python script from a shell script

Tags: python, shell

How do I read an argument with spaces when running a python script?

**UPDATE**:

Looks like my problem is that I'm calling the python script through a shell script:

This works:

```
> python script.py firstParam file\ with\ spaces.txt
# or
> python script.py firstParam "file with spaces.txt"

# script.py
import sys
print sys.argv
```

But, not when I run it through a script:

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python $@
```

Prints: **['firstParam', 'file', 'with', 'spaces.txt']**

But what I want is:
**['firstParam', 'file with spaces.txt']**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `"$@"` instead:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
python "$@"
```

Output:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh /tmp/test.py firstParam "file with spaces.txt"
['/tmp/test.py', 'firstParam', 'file with spaces.txt']
```

with `/tmp/test.py` defined as:

```py
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass the parameters from a shell script to another program, you should use `"$@"` instead of `$@`. This will ensure that each parameter is expanded as a single word, even if it contains spaces. `$@` is equivalent to `$1 $2 ...`, while `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`.

For example, if you run: `./myscript param1 "param with spaces"`:

- `$@` will be expanded to `param1 param with spaces` - four parameters.
- `"$@"` will be expanded to `"param1" "param with spaces"` - two parameters.