# To ignore space in python argparse

Tags: python

For below code,

```
import os
import shutil
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Test")
    ap.add_argument('-s', '--values', action="store", dest="values", nargs='+', type=str)
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    print args
```

Input to this code is

> `$python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC 90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC 90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC`

Actual output is

> `{'values': ['90030#95000#m#6099#base_case', '90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC', '90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC', '90033#95003#s#3#+300', 'ABC']}`

But, I need output as below by ignoring space in third argument.

> `{'values': ['90030#95000#m#6099#base_case', '90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC', '90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC', '90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC']}`

May I know how to pass the correct arguments

Comment: Surround the last argument with quotes `"90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an argparse problem. This is a *shell* problem. Your shell parses out the arguments and passes those on as an array to Python.

Tell the shell to not parse the string by putting quotes around those parts that form one argument:

```sh
$ python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC \
    90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC "90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC"
```

Note the `"90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC"` as the last argument.

You can also use a backslash to escape the space:

```sh
$ python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC \
    90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC 90033#95003#s#3#+300\ ABC
```

Demo using `csh` and your sample code:

```sh
% python test.py -s a b c
{'values': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
% python test.py -s a "b c"
{'values': ['a', 'b c']}
% python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC 90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC 90033#95003#s#3#+300\ ABC
{'values': ['90030#95000#m#6099#bc', '90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC', '90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC', '90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC']}
```

Comment: That didnt resolve. I am still getting same separated output. i am using /bin/csh shell

Comment: @Raghavan: `csh` doesn't differ in behaviour here, from what I can find. `argparse` certainly will honour spaces in arguments if correctly passed in by the shell.

Comment: @Raghavan: using the code in your question, running csh I can't reproduce the issue at all. All samples in my answer work and produce `90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC'` as the last value in the `values` list.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I was running this python script with one other shell script  to run this python script in background. That shell script resulted in that behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @Raghavan: sounds like you ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801258/read-argument-with-spaces-in-python-script-from-a-shell-script) then..

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the argument with quotes

> python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC 90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC "90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC"

Comment: That didnt resolve. I am still getting same separated output. i am using /bin/csh

Comment: @Raghavan: `csh` does not differ in behaviour here, see the [UNIX shell quote tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html).

Answer (score 1):

Surround the argument in either single or double quotes:

```
$ python test.py -s 90030#95000#m#6099#bc 90031#95001#s#1#+100ABC 90032#95002#s#2#+200ABC '90033#95003#s#3#+300 ABC'
```